# Pandas to_json in separate lines

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the json format from pandas, where each rows are separated with new line.  For example if I have a dataframe like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


print("First:\n", df.to_json(orient="records"))

print("Second:\n", df.to_json(orient="records", lines=True))
```

Output:

```
First:
 [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]
Second:
 {"a":1,"b":2}
{"a":3,"b":4}
```

But I really want an output like so:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2},
{"a":3,"b":4}]
```

or

```
[
 {"a":1,"b":2},
 {"a":3,"b":4}
]
```

I really just want each line to be separated by new line, but still a valid json format that can be read.  I know I can use `to_json` with `lines=True` and just split by new line then `.join`, but wondering if there is a more straight forward/faster solution just using pandas.

Comment: You could take your first output and do a string replace, eg 
`'[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]'.replace(",{", ",\n{")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `indent` parameter

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2},
        {'a': 3, 'b': 4}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.to_json(orient="records", indent=1))
```

```
#output :
[
 {
  "a":1,
  "b":2
 },
 {
  "a":3,
  "b":4
 }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was converting a large csv file to Json and pandas kept returning a single line file that was impossible to read

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
import json

list(json.loads(df.to_json(orient="index")).values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add the brackets:

```
print(f"First:\n[{df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)}]")
print(f"Second:\n[\n{df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)}\n]")
```